# summon-ARM toolchain and eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, arm, stm32

I've having a bear of a time getting the summon-arm toolchain to work with eclipse  in Linuxmint Nadia MATE. I'm trying to compile a simple LED blinker example.  I've added all the directories for the STM32F4 to the include paths, and and the #include statements resolve, but I'm getting all sorts of unresolved references.  ~/bin/sat is in my $PATH, and the toolchain is clearly being found. I'm also getting a funny undefined reference to `_exit' which is pointing to somewhere in my Downloads directory, and I can't understand why Eclipse is looking there at all.

I'm a real newbie to Eclipse (probably obvious) and the ARM platform, but fairly experienced with programming PICs from a windows environment.

I have a feeling I'm missing something fairly simple (except for that '__exit' thing), but I haven't found the illuminating moment at SO (even though the same type of issue keeps popping up, I can't seem to locate the solution).  Thought I'd ask again before trying CooCox.

```
#include <stm32f4xx_conf.h>
#include "stm32f4xx_gpio.h"
#include "stm32f4_discovery.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_rcc.h"

void Delay(__IO uint32_t nCount) {
  while(nCount--) {
  }
}

void init_GPIO(void){
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE);
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_15 | GPIO_Pin_14 | GPIO_Pin_13 | GPIO_Pin_12;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_OUT;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);


    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0;        // we want to configure PA0
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN;     // we want it to be an input
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;//this sets the GPIO modules clock speed
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;   // this sets the pin type to push / pull (as opposed to open drain)
    GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_DOWN;   // this enables the pulldown resistor --> we want to detect a high level
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);           // this passes the configuration to the Init function which takes care of the low level stuff
}



void main(){
    init_GPIO();
    GPIOD->BSRRL = 0xF000; // set PD12 thru PD15
    Delay(1000000L);         // wait a short period of time
    GPIOD->BSRRH = 0xF000; // reset PD12 thru PD15
    uint8_t i = 0;


while(1){
    /* Every GPIO port has an input and
     * output data register, ODR and IDR
     * respectively, which hold the status of the pin
     *
     * Here the IDR of GPIOA is checked whether bit 0 is
     * set or not. If it's set the button is pressed
     */
    if(GPIOA->IDR & 0x0001){
        // if the number of button presses is greater than 4, reset the counter (we start counting from 0!)
        if(i > 3){
            i = 0;
        }
        else{ // if it's smaller than 4, switch the LEDs

            switch(i){

                case 0:
                    GPIOD->BSRRL = 0x1000; // this sets LED1 (green)
                    GPIOD->BSRRH = 0x8000; // this resets LED4 (blue)
                    break;

                case 1:
                    GPIOD->BSRRL = 0x2000; // this sets LED2 (orange)
                    GPIOD->BSRRH = 0x1000; // this resets LED1
                    break;

                case 2:
                    GPIOD->BSRRL = 0x4000; // this sets LED3 (red)
                    GPIOD->BSRRH = 0x2000; // this resets LED2
                    break;

                case 3:
                    GPIOD->BSRRL = 0x8000; // this sets LED4
                    GPIOD->BSRRH = 0x4000; // this resets LED3
                    break;
                }

            i++; // increase the counter every time the switch is pressed
        }
        Delay(3000000L); // add a small delay to debounce the switch
    }
    }


}
```

When I build, I get

```
make all 
Building file: ../src/main.c
Invoking: Cross ARM C Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -O0 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall  -g3 -I"/home/scott/workspace/STM32 libraries/CMSIS/Include" -I"/home/scott/workspace/STM32 libraries/CMSIS/ST/STM32F4xx/Include" -I"/home/scott/workspace/STM32 libraries/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/inc" -I"/home/scott/workspace/STM32 libraries/STM32F4-Discovery" -I/home/scott/workspace/blinky2/src -MMD -MP -MF"src/main.d" -MT"src/main.d" -c -o "src/main.o" "../src/main.c"
../src/main.c:41:6: warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int' [-Wmain]
 void main(){
      ^
Finished building: ../src/main.c

Building target: blinky2.elf
Invoking: Cross ARM C Linker
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -O0 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall  -g3 -Xlinker --gc-sections -Wl,-Map,"blinky2.map" -o "blinky2.elf"  ./src/main.o   
./src/main.o: In function `init_GPIO':
/home/scott/workspace/blinky2/Debug/../src/main.c:21: undefined reference to `RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd'
/home/scott/workspace/blinky2/Debug/../src/main.c:27: undefined reference to `GPIO_Init'
/home/scott/workspace/blinky2/Debug/../src/main.c:28: undefined reference to `RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd'
/home/scott/workspace/blinky2/Debug/../src/main.c:36: undefined reference to `GPIO_Init'
/home/scott/sat/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/cortex-m4/libg.a(lib_a-exit.o): In function `exit':
/home/scott/Downloads/summon-arm-toolchain-master/build/arm-none-eabi/thumb/cortex-m4/newlib/libc/stdlib/../../../../../../../gcc-linaro-4.8-2013.07-1/newlib/libc/stdlib/exit.c:65: undefined reference to `_exit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [blinky2.elf] Error 1

11:39:28 Build Finished (took 3s.124ms)
```

Comment: Are you satisfied with my answer?

Comment: Not quite.  The major part is the unresolved calls in the stm32 library, and why the exit call is looking in a directory that it should even know about.  Thanks, though.  I'm starting to think that I may need to include the .c files from the library in my link path, but haven't had a chance to test that yet

Comment: Okay, I edited my answer with an explanation. Regarding the stm32 library, you get the undefined reference errors because you didn't add the .c files of the library, you have to add those files to the list of files getting compiled.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try to verify the need to have the c files in the library in the include path.  Never seen that in the good old PIC days!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your toolchain is using the newlib C Library. Newlib is a minimal C library which is very flexible, and this flexibility is achieved by letting you define some functions which are part of the library. Those functions are called "stubs" see [this site](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/industry-comment/4023922/Embedding-GNU-Newlib-Part-2) for an example implementation of some newlib stubs. For example by defining those functions you can have `printf` using UART, the USB, etc.

The file `exit.c` in your case is calling your implementation of the stub `_exit`. You can implement a dummy stub as you should normally not need this system call on an embedded system.

Edit:

You probably built the summon-arm-toolchain using the build script provided [here](https://github.com/esden/summon-arm-toolchain/blob/master/summon-arm-toolchain). This script downloads newlib and adds a symbolic link in the GCC installation folder pointing to the newlib download location:

```
# line 420 and 421 of the script:
log "Adding newlib symlink to gcc"
ln -f -s `pwd`/${NEWLIB}/newlib ${GCC}
```

Since you probably built your toolchain while you were in the folder `/home/scott/Downloads/summon-arm-toolchain-master/`, the newlib library is now located in a subfolder of this path, where the build script downloaded it.

Comment: Thanks!  So I just need to find and point that link to the right path, and make my own exit.c